# What is a java collection?

Tags: java, collections

I want to know: What is a collection in Java?

Comment: edited the previous edit, there is no point creating a "googleable" tag

Comment: I would like a "Googeable" badge

Comment: As someone who struggles with learning himself. Let me offer some constructive criticism. Do your homework first and show others the fruit of such labor. Google this question first. Then create some concrete examples and see if others can critique your understanding. In this way you build respect for yourself, and respect others too. Best of luck. We all learn.

Comment: Does anyone one realize that almost 100% of the time people arrive at a stackoverflow question by googling and that googling again just brings you back to here?

Answer (score 27):

Usually an instance of [java.util.Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Collections.html) (although [java.util.Map](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) is officially also a part of the collections framework)

Although the Collection interface can be implemented directly, usually client code will use an implementation of one of the sub interfaces: [Set](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), [List](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html), [Queue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) / [Deque](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html)

Here is some sample code (on the left side you will usually see an interface and on the right side an implementation class).

[Sets](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) don't store duplicates, all of their elements are unique:

```
final Set<String> basicSet = new HashSet<String>();
basicSet.add("One");
basicSet.add("Two");
basicSet.add("One");
basicSet.add("Three");
System.out.println(basicSet.toString());
// Output: [Three, One, Two]
// (seemingly random order, no duplicates)
```

[SortedSets](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) are a special case of sets that store elements in a specified order:

```
final SortedSet<String> sortedSet = new TreeSet<String>();
sortedSet.add("One");
sortedSet.add("Two");
sortedSet.add("One");
sortedSet.add("Three");
System.out.println(sortedSet.toString());
// Output: [One, Three, Two]
// (natural order, no duplicates)
```

[Lists](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) let you store a value multiple times and access or modify insertion order:

```
final List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
strings.add("Two");
strings.add("Three");
strings.add(0, "One"); // add item to beginning
strings.add(3, "One"); // add item at position 3 (zero-based)
strings.add("Three");
strings.add(strings.size() - 1, "Two"); // add item at last-but-one position
System.out.println(strings);
// Output: [One, Two, Three, One, Two, Three]
```

There is also a practical shorthand for defining a list:

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("One", "Two", "Three");
// this returns a different kind of list but you usually don't need to know that
```

etc.

To get a better understanding, read [The Collections Trail](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html) from the Sun Java Tutorial (online), or [Java Generics and Collections](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596527754) by Maurice Naftalin and Philip Wadler

Answer (score 13):

I think this question is best answered in a non-programming sense.

Say you have 5 balls, and you want to move them around easily. You get a bag and place the 5 balls inside of it. The bag acts as a container. You can now move this bag around, and so quite easily the 5 balls move with it.

Simply put, your holding zero or more objects, inside another object for easy retrieval.

Answer (score 12):

`Collection` is an interface in the Java API, and [according to the docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) it is...

> The root interface in the collection hierarchy. **A collection represents a group of objects, known as its elements.** Some collections allow duplicate elements and others do not. Some are ordered and others unordered. The JDK does not provide any direct  implementations of this interface: it provides implementations of more specific subinterfaces like Set and List. This interface is typically used to pass collections around and manipulate them where maximum generality is desired.

Common examples of collections are: [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html), [`LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html), [`Stack`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) and [`Vector`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html).

Comment: thank you to tell me,
plz explain me what is inner class and outer class in java

Comment: Use this field to add comments to the answer. Use the *Ask Question* link for asking new questions :)

Answer (score 3):

It's a class that implements java.util.Collection interface.

There's another branch for those that implement java.util.Map.

These are the basis for data structures in Java: List, Set, LinkedList, HashMap, TreeMap, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting [Java API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/intro/index.html#PageTitle) "A collection — sometimes called a container — is simply an object that groups multiple elements into a single unit."