# Array that does not allow duplicates (Java)

Tags: java, arrays

I'm sure there is a simple answer to this because I think I have used or heard of it previously but can't seem to find it, possibly because Google doesn't understand English. Basically I need something similar or the same as an array that does not allow duplicate values (in Java).

Example: int[] example = {1,2,2,3,4,4}

would be {1,2,3,4}

Hopefully this is clear enough for a human to understand even if Google couldn't.

Comment: My vote for the excuse of the day goes to "because Google doesn't understand English" :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use a Set implementation. And also an array in Java cannot behave like a set, but with a Set implementation like `HashSet` it is possible to manage the uniqueness of the elements within your collection.

Comment: +1 a `Set<Integer>` such as `LinkedHashSet<Integer>` or `TreeSet<Integer>`

Comment: I was always under the impression that a Set held key and value pairs, I think I am a little confused with a Map.

Comment: Maby Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599243/what-is-a-java-collection

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HashSet`. 
For integers it will work fine. But later if you plan to store `Objects`, you should override `hashCode()` and `equals()` method. Because HashSet internally uses `equals()` and `hashcode()` to check for equality.

[Read More about hashcode and equals here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074996/hashcode-and-equals-method-in-java-object---a-pragmatic-concept.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Set` implementations

for example :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<Integer> numbers = new HashSet<>();

    numbers.add(3);
    numbers.add(5);
    numbers.add(5);
    numbers.add(5);
    numbers.add(6);
    numbers.add(12);

    System.out.println(numbers);   
}
```

will produce:

```
[3, 5, 6, 12]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 import java.util.HashSet;
 import java.util.Set;
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 Set<Integer> numbers = new HashSet<Integer>();

 numbers.add(3);
 numbers.add(5);
 numbers.add(5);
 numbers.add(5);
 numbers.add(6);
 numbers.add(12);

 System.out.println(numbers);   
 }
 Take this.you can get what you want to get.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for removing duplicates using `Hashset`

```
 public static Integer[] removeDuplicateUsingSet(Integer[] example) {
    List<Integer> inputList = Arrays.asList(example);
    Set<Integer> inputSet = new HashSet<Integer>(inputList);
    Integer[] ints = new Integer[inputSet.size()];
    int index = 0;
    for (Integer i : inputSet) {
        ints[index++] = i;
    }
    return ints;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Integer[] example = { 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4 };
    example = removeDuplicateUsingSet(example);
    for(int i = 0 ;i < example.length;i++){
        System.out.println(example[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**If can Use Hash Set while adding a element it won't allow Duplicate value or else u can use like this:**

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Arrays;
 public class NotDuplicateArray {

        /**
         * @param args
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Integer[] Value={1,2,2,3,3,4,5,6,6};
            ArrayList<Integer> Check=new ArrayList<Integer>();
            int count=0;
            int x = 1;

            for(int i=0;i<Value.length;i++){
                if(Check!=null){
                    if(!Check.contains(Value[i])){
                        Check.add(Value[i]);
                    }

                }else{
                    Check.add(Value[i]);
                }

            }
            for(int v:Check){
                System.out.println(v);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Output is [1,2,3,4,5,6]