# ArrayList/LinkedList get First Index number

Tags: java, list, arraylist, processing, indexof

Is is possible to get out of an `ArrayList` the first number of the first index?

Here's an Example:

In there are 5 items:

```
path = {0.5,5.0},{0.6,6.0},{0.7,7.0},{0.8,8.0},{0.9,9.0}
```

And I want to get the number `5.0` out of `{0.5,5.0}`...

I tried it with `path.get(0)` But it only gives me `{0.5,5.0}` back.

Is it possible to get `5.0` out of it without getting all the other numbers?

Comment: You have to get the array object from list to get from it second ([1]) element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your curly braces in the [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) are actually [brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket) (they probably are), you can use:

`myArray.get(0)[index]` to get the index you want. In your example it is:

```
myArray.get(0)[1];
```

Note: if your `ArrayList` elements are also `ArrayList` then you need to use `get(0).get(1)` instead of `get(0)[1]`.

Comment: Worked too :) Thx a lot

Answer (score 2):

If your `ArrayList` contains arrays, this is the way to go

```
myList.get(0)[1] // You're getting the index 1 from the 1st array of your ArrayList
```

Otherwise, if it is containing other `ArrayList's`

```
myList.get(0).get(1) // Same logic as above applied to the Collection
```

Comment: Collection does not have get(int).

Comment: @JakubKaszycki An ArrayList is called a Collection hence it extends AbstractCollection

Comment: `Collection` does not have method `E get(int)`. It's method of `List`, I meant

Comment: @JakubKaszycki [ArrayList is a Collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599243/what-is-a-java-collection) and I never said Collection had a get method... But whatever.

Comment: You just said "Same logic as above applied to the Collection"