# How do I use all the words entered in a for loop outside the loop

Tags: java

I am trying to make a Vocabulary Tester program where i first enter the words in another language then their translations and after those have been entered i want the program to ask back the translations and the user to enter the words in the language that the vocal is in.

This is as far as I've done:

```
package myVocabTester;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class VocabTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This program will help you to prepare for upcoming vocabulary tests!");

        int numWords = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter how many words you need to learn"));

        String trans = "";
        String language = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What language are the vocab words in?");

        for(int i = 1;i <= numWords;i++){
            String word = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter word "+i);
            trans = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter word "+i+"'s translation");


        }

        //String enter = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is"+trans+" in"+language"?");


    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a java collection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599243/what-is-a-java-collection)

Answer (score 1):

I would create a `POJO` (a new class with just getters and setters) which contains the information needed for one `translation`. In your case this is the original `word`, the `translation` and the `language`.
Then you can create such an object in the loop, add it to your `List` of these `Objects` and use them later as needed.
If you need additional information later like the `user` who created the `translation`, you can simply create new fields in your POJO, so your code is easiliy extendable.

```
class Translation {
    String word;
    String translation;
    String language;

    public Translation(String word, String translation, String language) {
        this.word = word;
        this.translation = translation;
        this.language = language;
    }

    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }

    public String getTranslation() {
        return translation;
    }

    public String getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }
}
```

And your code could look like:

```
String language = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What language are the vocab words in?");

List<Translation> translations = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 1; i <= numWords; i++) {
    String word = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter word " + i);
    String trans = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter word " + i + "'s translation");
    translations.add(new Translation(word, translation, languuage));
}

//do what you like with the List<Translation>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add each `trans` into a `Collection` after the user has entered. Once you have captured all the words, loop the collection and ask back!